# Extract substring from string using javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expressions in Javascript.

The string looks something like

```
Password=6)8+Ea:4n+DMtJc:W+*0>(-Y517;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppleTurnover;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Data Source=Sydney
```

and I am trying to extract from this just the bit

```
Password=6)8+Ea:4n+DMtJc:W+*0>(-Y517
```

from ths string.

So, I have:

```
string="`Password=6)8+Ea:4n+DMtJc:W+*0>(-Y517;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppleTurnover;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Data Source=Sydney"
substring=string.match('/Password=(.*);/g');
```

It returns back the entire string again. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I am using this tool: https://regex101.com/ Helps a lot

Comment: Thank you... Helped mate!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Regex should not be wrapped in quotes. Use `[^;]+` to select anything until `;`.

```
var password = string.match(/Password=([^;]+)/)[1];
```

```js
string = "`Password=6)8+Ea:4n+DMtJc:W+*0>(-Y517;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppleTurnover;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Data Source=Sydney";
var password = string.match(/Password=([^;]+)/)[1];

document.write(password);
```

Or lazy regex can also be used

```
/Password=(.*?);/g
             ^
```

```js
var string = "`Password=6)8+Ea:4n+DMtJc:W+*0>(-Y517;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppleTurnover;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Data Source=Sydney";
var password = string.match(/Password=(.*?);/g);
document.write(password);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's useful to think of the underlying grammar / syntax:

string := 'Password=' *password* ';' ...

So you want to match the non-semicolon characters.

```
string="`Password=6)8+Ea:4n+DMtJc:W+*0>(-Y517;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppleTurnover;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Data Source=Sydney"
/Password=([^;]+)/.exec(string)[0] // or [1] if you want just the password
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Simply try this `/Password.*;/`

So you start looking for a String with `Password` in the beginning, followed by whatever character, until you reach a `;`.

By using the `g` at the end of your RegEx, you are setting it for global, so you are not only looking for the first `;`, but for every one. This might have been the reason why yours did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using potential reserved words.

Your first regular expression worked, you just added useless quote around it. Removig it will works.

```
var myString = "`Password=6)8+Ea:4n+DMtJc:W+*0>(-Y517;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=AppleTurnover;Initial Catalog=ProductDB;Data Source=Sydney"
var mySubstring = myString.match(/Password=(.*);Persist /g); // Remove the ' around the regex
var thePassword = mySubstring[0].replace('Password=', '');
thePassword = thePassword.replace(';Persist ', '');
```